# Заполнение SVG несколькими градиентами

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, svg

Есть ли способ заполнить SVG двумя или тремя цветами градиента?
Используя следующий способ, я могу заполнить конкретный путь SVG одним цветом.

`$("#canvas-area").click(function (event) {
      $(event.target).css('fill', _'#000');
})`

Радиальный градиент можно использовать, но он не может работать динамически.
Цвета должны быть определены в коде SVG.
Поэтому я хочу заполнить `SVG path`, используя два или три цвета в качестве градиента, следующим образом, используя `jQuery`.
И есть ли возможность сделать это, используя плагин [keith-svg](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)?

Источник: [Gradient fill SVG with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48125941/7394871)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48125941/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете динамически создать элемент `RadialGradient`, а затем применить его к свойству `fill`:

Это очень простой способ и нуждается в улучшении, чтобы рассматривать цвета и различные свойства как переменные.

**Для закраски градиентом кликнете по тексту**

```js
$("#canvas-area").click(function(event) {
  $('body').append('<svg id="grade-def"><defs><radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" /><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" /></radialGradient></defs></svg>');
  $(event.target).attr('fill', 'url(#grad)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="150" width="400" id="canvas-area">
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="#000" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="86">
  SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Вы также можете определить свой `RadialGradient` и просто изменить цвета при каждом клике  или другие свойства:
Смена градиента при каждом клике на тексте.

```js
let colors = ["green", "orange", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "red", "pink"]

$("#canvas-area").click(function(event) {
  $(this).find('#grad stop').eq(0).css('stop-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
  $(this).find('#grad stop').eq(1).css('stop-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
  $(event.target).attr('fill', 'url(#grad)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="150" width="400" id="canvas-area">
<defs>
<radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="#000" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="86">
  SVG</text>
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48125941/7394871)